# how to merge user generated data from different devices?

Tags: web, frameworks, merge

When a single user use several devices to generate data offline or online, how to merge it and avoid conflict as far as possible?

Like I made a game with several stages with offline capacity. A user Mike has came to stage 2 with score 123 in offline status on his iPad, but now he move to his iPhone and found that he is still in stage 1. So he play stage 1 again and reach stage 2 with score 321. When both his devices connect to internet, we want to synchronize these two devices to a single status. We may do:

- User click sync button on two devices and the application stop
- All devices push it all user data (score, stage...)
- Server merge the user data with last modify time
- All devices pull the merged data
- The application back to front page and resume to avoid inconsistency

This solution rely on application it self. Is there any solution to make the user data synchronization transparent to application?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a kind of *collaborative* stuff, you know, when several users editing the same document.

First, let's see how collaborative things should be implemented:

- client events must be sent to server,
- server sets the order of the events,
- server applies events on the data,
- server sends data changes to the clients.

It works well, if the server is always accessible. I've written a collaborative spreadsheet, and it was wonderful to see, when I entered 1.9999999 into the cell, it changed to 2.00, because 1.9999999 was only an event, which the server processed and made a 2.00 data from it and sent back.

If there is no server 7/24 available, you should

- keep a local copy of the data,
- use a *draft* event->data transformation,
- which *draft* data is displayed until the server sends the *official* data.

In most cases, official and draft data is the same, and it's even not necessary to warn the user, that what he or she can see, is a temporary data.

The main trick is that

- events should have a timestamp,
- the clients' time must be synchronised.

So, when the server comes back from the holiday, it will be able to re-play events in the correct order. Also, when another client joins after an offline period, and it sends past events, the server should have to re-run some past events from other clients to get correct final data calculated.

You may never sure, wheter all events are collected by the server. You have to work out a strategy, what to do with events from the far-far past. Maybe drop them?

Some cases, say, high score, order is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be not to require that both devices connect to the Internet at the same time and buttons are pushed on both.

You could do it this way:

1. At startup, the application checks if there is an Internet connection. If not, then starts based on its own data, otherwise it pushes the user data to the server.
2. When the server gets user data from a device, it does the merge: in your case it should check if the stage is higher than what it already knows about: if not, then just disregard the newly received data, otherwise overwrite the existing data with the newly received data.
3. if the data was updated, the server broadcasts the new data to all connected devices (this could happen mid-game)

If the server is not aware of the connected devices, then step 3 cannot work. The solution is to change step 1, so that at startup the application pushes the user data to the server (which does the merge right away) and then queries the user data from the server (might get the same or a higher stage) and starts based on whatever it received.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [transactional database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) on the server.

From Wikipedia:

1. Begin the transaction
2. Execute a set of data manipulations and/or
   queries
3. If no errors occur then commit the transaction and end it
4. If errors occur then rollback the transaction and end it

Your server-based database is the primary source of valid information for your clients. When clients want to know the latest score, they query the database. On your client, you keep track of `local_score` and `remote_score`. What you show to the user is `local_score+remote_score`, but when you submit a score update to the server, you only submit the portion that was earned for **that instance** of the game (`local_score`). The mindset is you only send the deltas. Your database simply adds any new scores it receives to its internal total, and does it in the transactional way shown above.

Note that the database will queue near-simultaneous requests and execute them sequentially, as it locks the relevant portion of the database while a transaction is occurring. You could build this logic all yourself, but with so many [good](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.mysql.com/&ei=4oB_UvzNLIj54APLhYHIDw&usg=AFQjCNGTx-3Plb9D7H7kow-uAyIZnQPWnw&sig2=4v3EYIeAoCe_IYigvOh-2g&bvm=bv.56146854,d.dmg), [free](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.sqlite.org/&ei=-YB_UqvPLtLb4APbq4CwDg&usg=AFQjCNEakQjCFFXx7pu-fq8qk9wUOlC1Bg&sig2=1IIVtx5R2pzVX4pAB7bHMg&bvm=bv.56146854,d.cWc) [databases](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAA&url=http://www.postgresql.org/&ei=CoF_UoPPIOessASv0oFg&usg=AFQjCNHhuOZnVQteX8H9LuxN9CJBVzl4ZA&sig2=k0LgVetNtjbdcKERnrbbxQ&bvm=bv.56146854,d.cWc) out there, you can just use one of them.

This strategy allows your clients to be as up-to-date as the server is whenever they update, while pushing the responsibility to the server to be the authoritative source of information about the game state. Of course, you don't just do this with the score, but with anything you need to keep track off across multiple clients.